# Get a list in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a website and users can add friends. I want them to be able to see their personal friends on a page.

For exemple:

John add user Tim and Bill.

When John goes on his friends list page, I want him to be able to see that he has Tim and Bill. How do I do that? Is that even possible? Do I need more than one table? If so, does every user has to have his own friendsList table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you do this by querying the information from the database, the answer for if you need multiple tables etc all depends on your current table structure but at the very least you need to have some way of referencing that a Person 'John' has friends, wether thats just a 'friendID' in the same 'Person' table, or another means of doing so. then it is just a matter of querying the data correctly to return what you want and bind to the websites fields :D

Answer (score 0):

One way of defining the structure is the following:

**Person**

```
PersonId
Name
<other person fields>
```

**Relationship**

```
RelationshipId
Name                     --> allow to define multiple relation types like Friendship, Follows etc.
```

**Relationship**

```
RelationshipId
Person1Id                --> FK to Person
Person2Id                --> FK to Person
RelationshipTypeId       --> FK Relationship
```

Basically, you use an n:n between `Person`s (anyone can have any number of friends) and also allow for other types of relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a table of users, one approach would be to create a "friends" table which relates users to other users.

```
 CREATE TABLE friends (
   `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
   `friend_id` INT NOT NULL
 );
```

Both user_id and friend_id would have foreign key constraints on your existing users table (so that you guarantee an id must exist in your user table in order for it to exist in the friends table as either a user_id or friend_id).

You can then link your user table on users.id = friends.friend_id to get the friend's info.

[Here is a SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/849c9/10) showing how this works.

You should consider using an [ON DELETE CASCADE constraint](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) on the friends table, so that if a user is deleted from the user table, the associated records in the friends table are also deleted.